# Set class attribute values in a generator

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have a list of lists. Each sublist contains objects of a custom class. What I want to do is set a certain attribute of each class object to 0. The simple way to do this would be a double for loop or similar:

```
for subl in L:
  for myObj in subL:
    myObj.attr = 0
```

Alternatively, I could use `itertools.chain`:

```
for myObj in itertools.chain.from_iterable(L):
  myObj.attr = 0
```

However, I wonder if I could set everything in one line. Could I perhaps use a generator-like structure to do this? Something along the lines of:

```
(myObj.attr=0 for subl in L for myObj in subl)
```

Now that won't really work, and will raise a SyntaxError, but is something even remotely similar possible?

Comment: You could write a function that does it and then do `(myFunc(myObj) for subl in L for myObj in subl)`.  But why?  You don't really gain anything by getting it all on one line.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's possible… just for fun, I suppose (`fun` I live a sad, sad life)

Comment: Yes but why go through these code gymnastics? 2 months down the line when you go back to your code, you'll be scratching your head at what's going if you did it the "one liner" way vs. the more verbose but clearer for loop.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: This is not meant for something in prod. This is just for fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an abuse of generator expressions, but:

```
any(setattr(obj, "attr", 0) for sub in L for obj in sub)
```

Or, perhaps slightly faster since there's no testing of each object:

```
from collections import deque
do = deque(maxlen=0).extend

do(setattr(obj, "attr", 0) for sub in L for obj in sub)
```

Comment: That `any`, exploiting `setattr`'s `None` retval is awesome hackery!

Comment: Yeah, it's just a little unclear... I actually like the `do` function better since it explicitly ignores the return value.

Answer (score 1):

See this example:

```
class C:
def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
    def f(self, para):
        self.a = para

list1 = [C() for e in range(3)]
list2 = [C() for e in range(3)]
list3 = [list1, list2]

[c.f(5) for l in list3 for c in l]

for e in list3:
    for c in e:
        print c.a
```

**Conclusion**

You could create a method to set the attribute. It will look something like:

```
[myObj.setattr(0) for subl in L for myObj in subl]
```

Note the **brackets**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a  simple solution that popped out in my head.

Using the built-in `setattr`, your suggestion - `itertools.chain.from_iterable` -, and an abuse of list comprehension:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        my_attr = 10
A = Foo()
B = Foo()
C = Foo()
D = Foo()

obj_list = [[A, B], [C, D]]
a = [setattr(obj, "my_attr", 0) for obj in itertools.chain.from_iterable(obj_list)]
```

Result:

```
>>> a
[None, None, None, None]
>>> A.my_attr
0
>>> B.my_attr
0
>>> C.my_attr
0
>>> D.my_attr
0
```

I found `setattr` to be very useful for cases like this, it's simple, short, and effective.

Hope this helps!